# SQL doesn't update when trying to pass array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, session

I'm trying to input some values in `event.php` and store them in an array (`$mem`). I'm then passing this array in another `eventregister.php` file where I'm inserting it in MySQL table.

Starting lines in my event.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$sess_uid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sess_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$sess_name = $_SESSION['name'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='register1')
    require_once('13/functions/eventregister.php');    
?>
```

In `<body>`:

```
    ...
    ...
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE slug = '".$slug."'");
    if ($result == true){
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id=$row['id']; 
        }
    $_SESSION['eventid']=$id;
    $_SESSION['eventname']=$row['name'];
    $_SESSION['max_members']=$row['members'];

    php $mem=array_fill(0,$row['members'],'');?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php for ($i=0;$i<$row['members']-1;$i++){
        echo '<label>TRYST ID of Member '.($i+1).' :</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" size="20" name="'.$mem[$i].'"><br>';
    }
    echo '<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" name="register1">Register</button>';?>
    </form>
```

My eventregister.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
    foreach($_POST['mem'] as $key=>$value){
        $value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        if(strlen($value)==0)
            $value="Null";
    }

    $sess_uid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sess_email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $sess_name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $e_id=$_SESSION['eventid'];
    $e_name=$_SESSION['eventname'];
    $e_max_mem=$_SESSION['max_members'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregister(event_id,event_name,max_number) VALUES('".$e_id."','".$e_name."','".$e_max_mem."')");
    $url="events.php?slug=".$slug;
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
?>
```

The page doesn't show any error, redirects are working, its just that no rows get affected in SQL. I'm still in the learning process, hence using the old notations of PHP.

Comment: What's the deal with `$value` in `eventregister.php`? You assign it more than once and then don't use it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Those values will also get saved, but I was first trying to check whether I'm passing the array correctly or not.

Comment: Do `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` this will tell you exactly why.

Comment: Also try and echo the sql statement out before sending it

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I tried deleting the whole block, still the values weren't added to the SQL table.

Comment: @Gerve: It doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the `INSERT` statement, you see you have a stray comma at the end. Remove that:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregister(event_id,event_name,max_number) 
      VALUES('".$e_id."','".$e_name."','".$e_max_mem."')");
```

You could also see the MySQL error in your server logs. Or call [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to find out more if a query fails.

I also do not see a `mysql_connect` anywhere.

Comment: Check the return value of `mysql_query` and call `mysql_error` if it fails. Also, check your logs to find the SQL error.

Comment: There are no errors. I checked twice. Also, I've checked the SQL tables' name. Am I passing the array correctly?

Comment: You are not passing any array, but a few variables. What is the result code of mysql_query, and what does mysql_affected_rows say?

Comment: I want to pass the input fields in the `<form>` as an array. The array is `$mem`

Comment: Well, you aren't doing that. And why do you want to? I advise you to get the PHP and MySQL basics first before you try to do anything complex.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24126/discussion-between-xan-and-bart-friederichs)

Comment: I'm still in the learning process. What I wanted was to pass an array and then insert it in the SQL table. Can you help me in doing that? I tried many things, read many SO posts.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to teach you PHP/MySQL. If you come up with a self-contained example I could give you some hints.

Comment: Okay. This is a snippet of my code regarding the form input in the array. :http://dpaste.com/912981. I guess it is correct. I just need some advise in passing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your commas and brackets not organised

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregister(event_id,event_name,max_number) VALUES('".$e_id."','".$e_name."','".$e_max_mem."')");
```

Comment: The problem is still there.